# firebase-perf make gradle takes more than 7 mins every time run the app, Android studio 3.6.2

Tags: android, gradle, firebase-performance

**UPDATE:**
I commented `firebase-perf` codes and now it runs faster !
Any advice please ?

**OLD:**
Android studio 3.6.2 take more than 7 mins to run the app every time,
tried clean and invalidate and restart Android studio

also modified gradle.properties as

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

I think it was good before adding `firebase-perf` SDK

Module:app

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
// Create a variable called keystorePropertiesFile, and initialize it to your
// keystore.properties file, in the rootProject folder.
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('keystore.properties')

// Initialize a new Properties() object called keystoreProperties.
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()

// Load your keystore.properties file into the keystoreProperties object.
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'//   Authentication
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'//  Realtime Database
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.5'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.38.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.0.1' // ads

    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    //noinspection LifecycleAnnotationProcessorWithJava8
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'


}
```

project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Consider upgrading your machine with higher RAM and CPU speed, try resetting android studio and gradle to defaults

Comment: thank you, but this app only take long time, other apps take less than this app

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen, If you can help, please